# How to permanently add variables or string (to a list or dictionary) in any loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have to write a piece of code for an assessment for my course, the requirement that I am having difficulties completing is storing all of the room names into a list or dictionary straight from a loop. I have tried researching it but nothing really helps me do this specifically. As I am quite new to python, I would really appreciate a way to work this out in simpler terms.

This is my code:

```
print ("+++++++++++++++\nPRICE ESTIMATOR\n+++++++++++++++")

roomnames={}
cnumber = input("Please enter your customer number: ").upper()

dateofestimate = input("Please enter the estimated date (in the format dd/mm/yyyy) : ")

rooms = int(input("Please enter the number of rooms you would like to paint: "))

x = 0 

for i in range (0,rooms):
    x = x+1
    print("\nFOR ROOM:", str(x))
    Rname = input("Please enter a name: ")
    roomnames = {(x):(Rname)}

print(roomnames)
```

The output I get is like this:

```
FOR ROOM: 1
Please enter a name: lounge

FOR ROOM: 2
Please enter a name: kitchen

FOR ROOM: 3
Please enter a name: bedroom 1 

FOR ROOM: 4
Please enter a name: bedroom 2

{4: 'bedroom 2'}
```

I would like to store all of the room names and the room number it corresponds to, to get something like this:

```
{1: 'lounge', 2: 'kitchen', 3: 'bedroom 1', 4: 'bedroom 2'}
```

If there is a simpler way, like using a list I am happy for any advice on that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a longer code which checks for valid inputs:

```
#Let's first find nr (nr of rooms)
valid_nr_rooms = [str(i) for i in range(1,11)] #1-10
while True:
    nr = input("Please enter the number of rooms you would like to paint (1-10): ")
    if nr in valid_nr_rooms:
        nr = int(nr)
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")

#Now let's create a the dict
#But we could also use a list if the keys are integers!
rooms = {}
for i in range(nr):
    while True:      
        name = input("Name of the room: ").lower()
        # This checks if string only contains 1 word
        # We could check if there are digits inside the word etc etc
        if len(name.split()) == 1:
            rooms[i] = name
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use code like this:

```
rooms = int(input("Please enter the number of rooms you would like to paint: "))
roomandname= {i: input("Please enter a name: ") for i in range(rooms)}
```

Answer (score 1):

some thing like this would work:

```
RoomsNumberAndName.append(x)
Rname = input("Please enter a name: ")
RoomsNumberAndName.append(Rname)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, It managed to store all of the variables. however if i needed to call out one of the room numbers or names how would i go about doing that.

Comment: can you explain more? wht do you mean by calling out?

Comment: like if i wanted to print a particular roomname or roomnumber for example if room 2 was the kitchen how would i manage to print just the name of room 2 ?

Comment: you can put the append part under an if condition , like input('do you want to print this room name?')  if yes, then do append